# Prisma find many and count in one request

Tags: javascript, backend, prisma

I have a pagination in my category service, and I have to return obj with *total count of categories* and *data*

But there's can be some parameters. As example, I should return categories that was created by certain user:

```js
async findAll(
    { onlyParents }: ParamsCategoryDto,
    user: ITokenPayload | undefined,
): Promise<IFilterRes> {
    const categories = await this.prisma.category.findMany({
      where: {
        user_id: user?.id,
      },
    });

    return {
      pagination: {
        total: this.prisma.category.count({
          where: { // <- duplicate
          user_id: user?.id,
        },
      }),
    },
    data: categories,
  };
}
```

I should duplicate *where* in both query. Which is not very nice. Is there any option to do it in one request.

P.S. I can make some var for where, but in this way I lose typification, which I also don't like.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is my example code to acheive it with a single transaction, no duplicate code and not losing type autocomplete

```ts
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const findAll = async (userId: String) => {
  const query: Prisma.categoriesFindManyArgs = {
    where: {
      user_id: userId,
    }
  };
  const [categories, count] = await prisma.$transaction([
    prisma.categories.findMany(query),
    prisma.categories.count({ where: query.where })
  ]);

  return {
    pagination: {
      total: count
    },
    data: categories
  };
};
```

Comment: Oh, that's good alternative. It's very sad that prisma doesn't have such from a box. But I think you offer a really good way

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334140/5662244)

When you make some nested queries from another tables inside `findMany`, you should use `satisfies` instead strict type declaration, to make it exists in result type.

For example, instead

```
const query: Prisma.categoriesFindManyArgs = {
    where: {
      user_id: userId,
    }
};
```

you should write

```
const query = {
    where: {
      user_id: userId,
    }
} satisfies Prisma.categoriesFindManyArgs;
```

Now, Typescript will know and use exactly your type definition instead predefined and allow to you use all features of types inference